Long HTMEMO waits when deleting from columnstore index
I've a table that has a clustered columnstore index having 8 billion records. Once in a day, there is a process that inserts, updates and deletes data from this table with around 1-30 million record, from a table that holds the differential data for the day. All 3 statements join the 2 tables with the business key which is a combination of 8 columns. The proportion of records inserted:updated:deleted is like 4:4:2 - roughly. The update takes about 1 hour, the insert 1-2 minutes and the delete takes 1 hour.
Of late, the delete statement has begun to take very long times - sometimes 5 hours, sometimes even 8 hours. There is no change in the statement or the number of records being deleted. And the same statement could run in 1 hour on an odd day in the middle of 2 days of long running also. In short, the long running appears randomly, or without a detectable pattern/scenario. There is nothing else running on the server at this time also. This is on SQL 2016 on Azure VM.
On close live monitoring, noticed the presence of HTMEMO waits during the long running deletes. Some research on the net has shown this is related to the columnstore being unorganized/having lot of deleted records in deltastores, and index REORGANIZE being something that can help, a index REBUILD being better etc... Tried both - but no visible effect.
Anyone out there who has encountered such behavior ? What's going on, and why the random long running delete ? What can be done to fix the delete to make it faster ?
We've tried reorganizing & rebuilding the index on the big table, updated stats on the columns involved in the join...

This post suggested increasing cost threshold for parallelism and/or reducing maxdop. If this is the only statement affected, then you could do it on this statement. I hope it's separate statements and possibly using paging/batching and not a merge statement and all-at-once. (Also, it sounds like maybe a columnstore index isn't the right structure for that workload pattern.)

Yes, this is the only statement affected. And yes, it not a merge. Also, the design is inherited and we're looking at getting rid of the columnstore, but it can't be done overnight. So till then, we're curiously looking for an explanation of the random behaviour.

Did you investigate parallelism as an explanation of the behavior? You could easily add OPTION (RECOMPILE, MAXDOP <n>) and experiment with different values of <n> to see if you can come up with a runtime that's stable. I will say updates and deletes that take "about an hour" sounds... really not optimal in the first place. That it takes more hours sometimes wouldn't be my first area of concern.

Yes, RECOMPILE, MAXDOP and FORCE ORDER from the smaller table to the bigger one have been tried on the statement and have been there for last 10 days, without any apparent effect.
The thing about UPDATE is that it is stable - we know it will finish in an hour max!
